# Using CronTab to run php scripts

Tags: php, cron

I need to send emails hourly and daily. I've tried nearly everything but it appears my crontab just won't work. If I run the scripts via a browser e.g

```
http://localhost/Maisha/Functions/sendhourlymails.php
```

my emails get sent beautifully.(I moved default website localhost to public_html.) I don't know whats wrong. I read some post in stack overflow including the executable path of php helps hence I've put the /usr/bin/php before the actual script to be cronned will work but it does not. Removing /usr/bin/php does not work. Adding php before the actual script isn't working. 
I have the following entries in my crontab.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0  *  *   *   *    /usr/bin/php /home/maxwell/public_html/Maisha/Functions/sendhourlymails.php
0  0  *   *   *    /usr/bin/php /home/maxwell/public_html/Maisha/Functions/senddailymails.php
```

Comment: What happens if you run the command directly on the command line?

Comment: What happens when you run the commands manually on the command line?

Comment: have you looked for errors in the logs?

Comment: @Alister how do I do that? I'm a Newbie in linux environment

Comment: @Eineki How do I do that and which error logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to call the script via http with wget like so:

```
* * * * * wget http://localhost/myscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Do I put that in my crontab entries or wget is different?

Comment: wget is a unix utility like any other and cron executes whatever command (with limitations) you want.

Comment: By the way it is best if this is done as su i.e create this cron as super user.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, wget is good option, also you can try to use:

0  *  *   *   *    /usr/sbin/php /usr/bin/php /home/maxwell/public_html/Maisha/Functions/sendhourlymails.php

but it could work wrong due to relative paths.

Also you should look at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: usr/sbin/php does not exist for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this into your .php file

```
<?php
    #!/usr/local/bin/php -q
//your code here
?>
```

Then if you include any file into this file you must use something like:

```
include"/var/www/../your_absolute_path_from_root_folder/connect.php";
```

Finnaly make sure this file has the right permissions..Try

```
chmod 755 /var/www/.../file.php
```

Then if you edit your crontab file with the following command

```
vi /etc/crontab
```

put something like

```
10 6 * * * root php /var/www/..path../file.php
```

and restart the service with this command

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```

you have do your job!!

- Note-Tip:the php file isn't neccessery to be into public_html
  folder!!